# Integrate Contact Form 7 with external mailing list (Wordpress)

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

I need to integrate Contact Form 7 with a newsletter subscribe form so that when a "subscribe" checkbox is ticked, the contact form is sent and the contact details are sent to the newsletter list (similar to how the MailChimp plugin works). The newsletter app provides the following basic HTML signup form:

```
<form name="signup" id="signup" action="http://mailing-list.com/signup.ashx" method="post">
<p></p>
<input type="hidden" name="addressbookid" value="XXX">
<input type="hidden" name="userid" value="XXX">
<input type="hidden" name="ReturnURL" value="">
<table>
<tr>
<td>
Email</td><td><input type="text" name="Email"></td></tr>
<tr><td>FIRSTNAME</td><td><input class="text" type="text" name="cd_FIRSTNAME"/></td></tr>
<tr><td>LASTNAME</td><td><input class="text" type="text" name="cd_LASTNAME"/></td></tr>
</table>
<input type="Submit" name="Submit" value="Subscribe">
</form>
```

How do I integrate this with Contact Form 7?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually got it to work using a plugin to map the contact form fields to the external mailing list: http://wordpress.org/plugins/forms-3rdparty-integration

Comment: can you share the steps to integrate external form

Answer (score 0):

I was able to connect my [Contact Form 7 to Mailchimp](https://mailoptin.io/article/contact-form-7-mailchimp-aweber-more/) using MailOptin plugin as the bridge. And it's free in the WordPress plugin repo https://wordpress.org/plugins/mailoptin/

And it also support dozens of email marketing software and CRM and also support checking a checkbox before users are added to your integration.

[image]

Here’s the article on how to do it https://mailoptin.io/article/contact-form-7-mailchimp-aweber-more/

Hope that helps.